# WPF application Build error when using Extended WPF Toolkit Plus v2.1.0

Tags: wpf, code-generation, toolkit

My WPF Application works fine. But, since I tried to use ‘MaskedTextBox’ Control (Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.Plus.2.1.0) I got the following Build Error :

« The type or namespace name ‘Controls’ could not be found in namespace ‘Microsoft.Windows’(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) » File : ‘MasterMenu.g.cs’

The Window declaration (xaml) is as follows :

```
<Window x:Class="myProject.Presentation.MainModule.MasterMenu"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:CustomControls;assembly=MyGroupBox"
    Title="myApplication-Démonstration"        
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowState="Maximized" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded_1"
    Closed="Window_Closed">
```

And The ‘Using’ instructions in source file  ‘MasterMenu.cs’ are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Winlease.CrossCutting.Logging;
using CustomControls;
using UITools;
```

And The Using in the generated file ‘MasterMenu.g.cs’ are :

```
using CustomControls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using RootLibrary.WPF.Localization;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;
```

The 2 lines responsibles for the error

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

I deleted bin, obj directories and i clean the solution many times and I rebuild but error still exists.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Actually i forgot to add reference to WPFToolkit.dll in my Prject. That's all.

Thank you.